# binding selected items from one list box to another listbox

Tags: c#

I have two list boxes in my form. I bound some data in the first list box. Now I have to select the items from the first lis tbox and should bind those selected items to the second list box when I press the button which is between these two list boxes. I am able to bind a single item at a time but I am having problem binding multiple selected items.

I am using the following code:

```
Hashtable ht = new Hashtable();

            ht.Add(lbCATallSubcat.SelectedValue.ToString(),lbCATallSubcat.Text.ToString());
            int i = 0;
             foreach (string ent in ht.Values) {           
                string[] name = new string[lbCATallSubcat.Items.Count];

                for (i = 0; i < lbCATallSubcat.SelectedItems.Count; i++) {
                    name[i] = lbCATallSubcat.Text;
                    this.lbCATSelectedSubcat.Items.Add(name[i]);                
                }
                lbCATSelectedSubcat.DisplayMember = ht.Values.ToString();
                lbCATSelectedSubcat.ValueMember = ht.Keys.ToString();
            }
```

Comment: I'm a little confused. Do you want to bind the second list to the selected items of the first, or do you just want to copy the items when you click a button?

Comment: i want to bind the second list box with the selected items of first. im able to bind single seleted item but im unable to bind the multiple seleted items